# WinRTError: Class not registered

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, winjs, winapp

I'm new in TypeScript. 
I'm getting error when trying to instantiating the class.
Below is my sample code, actual code is different can't share.

```
 module ABC {
    export class A {    
       public execute<T>(action: string, data?: any, callerContext?: any): IAsyncResult<T> {
        // CODE::   
        var requestMessage = new Common.ClientClasses.ClientRequestMessage(); **// **ERROR- "WinRTError: Class not registered"****
        requestMessage.requestUri = actionRequest;
        requestMessage.method = "POST";
        requestMessage.body = data ? JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) : null;
        Common.ClientClasses.ClientRequest.executeAsync(requestMessage)
         .done((result: Common.ClientClasses.ClientResponeMessage) => {
             // CODE:
        }
        // Code::
      }
   }
}

declare module Common.ClientClasses {
    class ClientRequestMessage {
        public requestUri: string;
        public method: string;
        public body: string;
    }

    class ClientResponeMessage {
        public status: number;
        public statusText: string;
        public responseText: string;
    }

    class ClientRequest {
        static executeAsync(clientRequestMessage: ClientRequestMessage): any;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some improvements, should work:

```
module ABC {

    export class A {

        public execute<T>(action: string, data?: any, callerContext?: any) {
            var requestMessage = new Common.ClientClasses.ClientRequestMessage();
            requestMessage.method = "POST";
            requestMessage.body = data ? JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) : null;
            Common.ClientClasses.ClientRequest.executeAsync(requestMessage)
        }

     }
}

module Common.ClientClasses {

    export class ClientRequestMessage {
        public requestUri: string;
        public method: string;
        public body: string;
    }

    class ClientResponeMessage {
        public status: number;
        public statusText: string;
        public responseText: string;
    }

    export class ClientRequest {
        static executeAsync(clientRequestMessage: ClientRequestMessage): any {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Then it can be run as following:

```
var a = new ABC.A();
a.execute("some string");
```

`declare module` creates a definition file used for Intellisense but it doesn't provide any implementation that's why I changed your code so this fragment can work.

Also if you want to use any classes from the module, you must `export` them so they can be visible from outside of that module.

Comment: Sorry, not works. Getting same error on same line instance creation.

Comment: Not possible, I did test it.Did you add exports to classes in Common.ClientClasses module?