# WinRTError: Class not registered in Win10 UWP app

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Same error but not a duplicate of this question [WinRTError: Class not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435863/winrterror-class-not-registered)

I have a HTML/JavaScript UWP app that references some ClassLibraries and PortableClassLibraries. Everything works fine from Visual Studio, but if I create the Appx package myself via de [MakeAppx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tool (which I need to do) I get the

> WinRTError: Class not registered

error when my code tries to access static functions from the PCL.

I've found many errors like this that target Win8.1 and the proposed solution of adding an extension in the manifest of the app does not work on Windows 10. The schema of the manifest is different and it won't event compile the app.

Answer (score 0):

if you cant find the extensions in the manifest and that's not working:

```
<ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="x" ThreadingModel="both" /> <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="x" ThreadingModel="both" />
Where x is your classes full names..
```

Make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and the Windows SDK.. This kind of errors you fix it by this kind of actions.

Comment: For some reason that's not acceptable in Windows 10 (UWP) projects.